# how to write a query base on another tables value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables but I want to add a new identifier if

```sql
select a.* ,
case tax_year  
when to_char(report_end ,'YYYY') then    'Y' 
else 'N' 
end as wash_sale_3y_stats 
from fct_w_sales a, fct_by_lot b
where a.lot_id =b.unique_trade_identifier(+)   and tax_year = to_char(report_end(+) ,'YYYY')
order by a.client_id
```

`report_end` is in the `fct_by_lot`. The `report_end` is always the same, if we are in 2019 it will be 2019, for example.

But in `fcr_w_sales`, I need to pick the ones where `tax_year` is equal to the `report_end` that is why I wanted a flag, so that I can sum up the numbers.

the error message for this query is ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 6

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: OT, but bobody uses (+) notation for outer joins anymore.  Just modern sql syntax

Comment: @OldProgrammer - actually not true. I am currently on a gig where the standards still mandate the ANSI 89 join syntax. Personally I prefer explicit joins - especially for outer joins - but "standards is standards".

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works for you. I will add description of changes in code.

```
select a.* ,
       case tax_year  
       when extract(year from report_end) 
         then 'Y' 
         else 'N' 
       end as wash_sale_3y_stats 
  from fct_w_sales a 
  left join fct_by_lot b
    On a.lot_id = b.unique_trade_identifier  
   and tax_year = extract(year from report_end)
order by a.client_id
```

Cheers!!